# iOS 5 Landscape App. Works perfect. On iOS 6 device its locked to portrait

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've an app thats 100% in Landscape mode, and on iOS5 devices it appears that way. When I install it on iOS6 it is in Portrait mode.

In my info.plist i set

Supported interface orientations
item 0 : Landscape (right home button)
item 1 : Landscape (left home button)

I've read the documentation and added in the 2 new methods in my app delegate but its made no difference. Do I need to ahead and add these 2 methods to every root view(the view that appears on each tab) in the app?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{
return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return YES;
}
```

In every XIB in the project I've set Orientation: Landscape

Anybody able to suggest what it is I've missed out on implementing?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: Do you believe that `YES` is an `NSUInteger` ?  See here for a great lecture on auto rotations -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15942/conversation/auto-rotations-in-ios-6

Comment: Part 2 of the lecture -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15942/conversation/auto-rotations-part-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As states in the documentation the [`supportedInterfaceOrientations`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW120) that it should return a bit mask specifying which orientations are supported. Not a BOOL.

Thus you should return which interface orientation are supported, like:
`UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`,  `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown`, ....

Comment: But these masks are not supported on IOS 5 I believe.

Comment: True, you will need to implement both rotation ways if you want to support iOS5 and iOS6

Comment: Ok, if i add the code to my iOS5 project and try and build it complains about UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape .. can anybody advise me of the NSUInteger value to return so that it will compile using ios5, but that ios6 will understand to support Landscape modes?

Comment: Are you compile it with the iOS6 SDK, because I have not seen this error before.

Comment: No I've using a 5 sdk hence my problem. I believe I can get this to work if I can return the correct NSUInteger for Landscape support. Sorry for not mentioning this above.

Comment: You can't support app to the appstore that support iOS6 if they are not build using the iOS 6 SDK, You will need to switch to iOS 6 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The supportedInterfaceOrientations function returns the interfaceOrientations supported for the current controller. If your app itself does not support them, neither will this controller even if it returns them.

Solution: Add all the supported orientations to the summary tab in the project settings. Then controllers can individually choose supported orientations among the ones specified.